# Missing PC1 column to a PCA rotation

Tags: r, tidyr, pca

I'm trying to do PCA on the classic Iris data set. This is my code:

```
library(tidyverse)

x <- iris[,1:4] %>% as.matrix()
pca <- prcomp(x, scale. = TRUE)
summary(pca)
```

The component rotation has every value for Petal.Length, Petal.Width, etc. So I tried this:

```
as.data.frame(pca$rotation) %>% pivot_longer(-1, names_to = "components", values_to = "value")
```

I know there must be a mistake since `pca$rotation` is a matrix and somehow `PC1` is left out. The expected result should be:

```
terms          value component 
   <chr>          <dbl> <chr>   
 1 Sepal.Length  0.521  PC1     
 2 Sepal.Width  -0.269  PC1    
 3 Petal.Length  0.580  PC1    
 4 Petal.Width   0.565  PC1    
 5 Sepal.Length -0.377  PC2    
 6 Sepal.Width  -0.923  PC2     
 7 Petal.Length -0.0245 PC2      
 8 Petal.Width  -0.0669 PC2      
 9 Sepal.Length  0.720  PC3      
10 Sepal.Width  -0.244  PC3      
11 Petal.Length -0.142  PC3      
12 Petal.Width  -0.634  PC3    
13 Sepal.Length  0.261  PC4     
14 Sepal.Width  -0.124  PC4    
15 Petal.Length -0.801  PC4      
16 Petal.Width   0.524  PC4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `-1` specification of which variables to include left out the first column (you may have misread the row names, which are typically ignored by tidyverse machinery, as the first column).  How about

```
pca$rotation %>%
    as.data.frame() %>%
    rownames_to_column("term") %>%
    as_tibble() %>%    ## cosmetic
    pivot_longer(starts_with("PC"), 
                 names_to = "components", 
                 values_to = "value")
```

?

Comment: Thank you very much @Ben Bolker, that `rownames_to_column()` function is what did the trick! Your answer by the way made me investigate more, have a great day!